# How to let PySpark/Databricks job continue running and ignore bad records after a task failure

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am using Databricks and PySpark. `rdd` contains a list of file paths, then I process each files and generate some outputs.

`rdd.map(func).collect()` , where `func` will process each file to generate some outputs. However, `func` uses some C libraries and the bad file cause `segmentation fault` to the task process. I cannot catch the error.

Currently, the job fails because the tasks retry 4 times after connection reset. I do not want Spark to stop but instead continue processing remaining records, ignore the failed records, and restart a new task if it fails. It is fine to ignore those corrupt files. How can I set in Spark/Databricks?

Here is multiprocessing with timeout: if timeout due to `segmentation fault`, just kill this process and continue next process without crashing the main process. It works well without Spark, but fails in Spark because of pickle error and multiprocessing seems not supported in Databricks.

```
    with Pool(min(process_no, cpu_count())) as pool:
        pools = []
        for input in inputs:
            res = pool.apply_async(run_single, (input,))
            pools.append(res)
        for pool in pools:
            try:
                pool.get(timeout=20)
            except Exception as e:
                print("We lacked patience and got a multiprocessing.TimeoutError")
                continue
```

**Update:**

here is the code. I have 4 machines with 16 core (64 parallel tasks running).

```
def func(input):
    import signal
    def call_the_actual_logic(input):
        .....
        return [0]

    def timeoutHandler(signum, frame):
        raise TimeoutError("Task takes too long")

    try:
        # install a timeout handler inside of the Spark task
        # following https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#example
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeoutHandler)
        signal.alarm(10)  # cancel the task after 5 seconds

        # call the actual logic
        result = call_the_actual_logic(input)
        signal.alarm(0)

        return result
    except TimeoutError:
        print("Logic for input {} took too long. Cleaning up...".format(input))
        return []
    except Exception as e:
        print("Logic for input {} threw an exception. Cleaning up...".format(input))
        return []
    
a = rdd.repartition(2048).flatMap(func).collect()
```

Here is the exception thrown by Spark. I doubt some worker crashed because of some corrupt file and un-catched error because I see some processing errors. From the error below, it seems a different exception.  Is it possible to just ignore this corrupt file and restart the worker if it is crashed?

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 162 in stage 49.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 162.3 in stage 49.0 (TID 20313, 10.139.64.4, executor 4): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3638575280205630> in <module>
     87 
     88 
---> 89 a = rdd.repartition(2048).flatMap(main_run_spark).collect()

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in collect(self)
    901         # Default path used in OSS Spark / for non-credential passthrough clusters:
    902         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 903             sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    904         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    905 

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1304         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 
   1307         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    125     def deco(*a, **kw):
    126         try:
--> 127             return f(*a, **kw)
    128         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    129             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 162 in stage 49.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 162.3 in stage 49.0 (TID 20313, 10.139.64.4, executor 4): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:625)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:743)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:721)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:556)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:315)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:294)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$2(RDD.scala:1011)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2373)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$8(Executor.scala:677)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1581)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:680)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:728)
    ... 30 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2519)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2466)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2460)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2460)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1152)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1152)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1152)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2721)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2668)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2656)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:938)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2333)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2354)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2373)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2398)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1011)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1010)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor559.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:625)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:743)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:721)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:556)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:315)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:294)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$2(RDD.scala:1011)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2373)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$8(Executor.scala:677)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1581)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:680)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:728)
    ... 30 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the error and/or timeout handling inside of `func`, so that the exception handling happens for each Spark task independently.

To call the function use [flatMap](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.flatMap) instead of map so that `func` can either return one or zero results:

```python
def func(input):
    import signal
    def timeoutHandler(signum, frame):
        raise TimeoutError("Task takes too long")
    try:
         #install a timeout handler inside of the Spark task
         #following https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#example
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeoutHandler)
        signal.alarm(5) #cancel the task after 5 seconds

        #call the actual logic
        result = call_the_actual_logic(input)
        signal.alarm(0) 

        #return an iterator with a single element
        return iter([result])

    except TimeoutError:
        #handle a timeout and return an empty iterator
        print("Logic for input {} took too long. Cleaning up...".format(input))
        return iter([])
    except Exception:
        #handle any other exception and return an empty iterator
        print("Logic for input {} threw an exception. Cleaning up...".format(input))
        return iter([])

def call_the_actual_logic(input):
    #call the C libraries and return the result
    return ...

#trigger the calculation
rdd2 = rdd.flatMap(func)
```

*Disclaimer*: I have tested this code on a plain vanilla Spark installation on a Linux box, not in Databricks notebook

Comment: Thanks! I am testing it now. So far so good!

Comment: I made some updates on the questions, it seems some workers still crashed.